# "./" does not work in "gcloud compute ssh test --command"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

We have one main script in Google Cloud Ubuntu VM that executes many other scripts.

I am trying to execute main script from Windows Google Cloud SDK with command:

```
gcloud compute ssh vm --command="./main.sh"
```

But all I get -

> ./main.sh File or directory does not exists

Commands that successfully runs `main.sh`:

```
gcloud compute ssh vm --command="/main.sh" 
gcloud compute ssh vm --command="bash -h /main.sh"
```

but fails for all other scripts with same error

> ./script.sh File or directory does not exists

Problem that all scripts contain `./` and would be nightmare to change all of them written by devs.

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Because there are no `main.sh` in your `$HOME`.

You can run

```
gcloud compute ssh vm --command="cd / && ./main.sh"
```

Comment: thanks, Cloud Ace, by running this command I got error:
`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) unrecognized arguments: /`
something wrong with `gloud ssh` pipeline?

Comment: Hmm, how about `ssh VM -- "cd / && ./main.sh"`

Comment: got error on same server:
`'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`.
But your command works on my pc where I have ssh installed.

Comment: I see. Where are you running this command? WSL?  Try installing ssh

Comment: but `ssh` does not support authentication without password, that's why I am using `gcloud`

Comment: `gcloud` uses `ssh` to establish ssh connection, you need `ssh` anyway. Can you rephrase your problem?  `gcloud compute ssh vm --command="/main.sh" ` is OK, so `ssh` is not a problem. Are you running the command on another machine? What happens if you run above `cd / && ./main.sh` command on the same machine you run `/main.sh`?

Comment: `cd / && ./main.sh` this works fine on Google vm, but command `gcloud compute ssh test --command="cd / && ./main.sh"` on remote server and my pc still shows same error. SSH command works from my pc, but not installed on the server there I run `gcloud`. So if no more options to resolve `gcloud` error I will try to install openSSH on that remote server and play with ssh keys for auto authentication as we need execute scheduled `cmd` script to trigger `bash` scripts in Google vm

Comment: `ssh` is required, as `gcloud` relies on it. But you don't need to play with keys as gcloud will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change those files batched by script or on the command line using perl or sed which are both capable to directly edit a file.
Here a working example that can even be simply used on the commandline.
Replace startdir with the full path to the script sources.
It assumes, that
- your scripts end with ".sh", needs customization
- that it is safe to substitute this expression in the whole script
- that this substitution needs to be done onle 1 time per line

```
find startdir -name "*.sh" -print | xargs sed -i -e "s/\.\/main\.sh/\/main\.sh/"
```

The elegance here is that xargs feeds the sed command maximum possible amount of filenames that are found, to reduce the amount of sed executions to the minimum and not exceeding the max length of a command line.

You could even work it out more in a shell script, that you could add different substitutions shall the remote scripts have different names.

Alternatively you could try to change the HOME directory of the remote user / machine where those script run so that at the end the path is correct for "./main.sh".
But this could have other impact, I would not really recommend this.

I am not sure whether I fully understand your problem, maybe you need to combine my "one liner" with the other proposal to first change the directory to "/" and then start the script with "./" as "." is usually not in the PATH. Then you have to modify the substitution like this:

```
find startdir -name "*.sh" -print | xargs sed -i -e "s=\./main\.sh=cd / \&\& \./main\.sh="
```

Comment: I think all other scripts are called from main.sh, so just changing the working directory is the simpiest way to solve the problem.

Comment: You could be right. Sorry, I didn't fully understand the issue from the description. But now he has the option to combine your proposal together with mine. So lets see what he finally tells. Then thanks for your proposal.